# How to position 8 pictures in a single page as a grid as shown

Tags: tables, includegraphics

I have 16 images and I am trying to position their denoised and noised version in a grid as shown in the figure using latex. need help with latex code
[image]

Comment: You can insert a table inside a figure as ```\begin{figure} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{figure}``` and include graphics in each cell.

Comment: You seem to have much more than eight images. Can you please be more precise?

Comment: Yes, i have 16 images with different variations of the same image. so totally 16 rows, i have showed only 7 rows in image mentioned above. and the columns are for different variations of the same image

Comment: Your requirements, as far as images per page go, are unclear. The title of your posting mentions **8 images per page**, or 4 rows of two images each. Elsewhere, you appear to mention (a) 16 rows of images, or **32 images per page**, and, in the comment above, (b) **16 images per page** (?), or 8 rows of images. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the `figure` environment should display 8, not 16, rows of images. If this assumption is correct, the following code may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p!]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\setkeys{Gin}{height=0.1\textheight,width=0.1\textheight} 

\caption{[Something Descriptive for Method 1]} % provide a suitable caption
\bigskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} r @{} *{2}{M{0.1\textheight}} @{}}
& Method 1 & Residual \\
\llap{Image 1\quad} & \includegraphics{fig1a} & \includegraphics{fig1b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 2\quad} & \includegraphics{fig2a} & \includegraphics{fig2b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 3\quad} & \includegraphics{fig3a} & \includegraphics{fig3b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 4\quad} & \includegraphics{fig4a} & \includegraphics{fig4b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 5\quad} & \includegraphics{fig5a} & \includegraphics{fig5b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 6\quad} & \includegraphics{fig6a} & \includegraphics{fig6b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 7\quad} & \includegraphics{fig7a} & \includegraphics{fig7b} \\ \addlinespace
\llap{Image 8\quad} & \includegraphics{fig8a} & \includegraphics{fig8b} 
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```